# How to force gatsby build even with errors

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am having an issue when running `gatsby build` that seems to be fairly common.

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 5.310s

ERROR #95312 

"window" is not available during server side rendering.

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html

ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

so, following multiple articles over the internet I first tried the approach of checking if I am in a browser environment.

```
const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
```

The build still breaking, so this made me believe the error is coming from a 3rd party dependency I have in my project.

So I followed other solutions to add some configurations on `gatsby-config.ts` to "bypass" some build steps.

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, loaders, stage }: any) => {
  if (stage === 'build-html' || stage === 'develop-html' || stage === 'develop') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /filler-module/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  }
};
```

which didnt work as well.

So, my idea was to somehow bypass this check when I run `gatsby build`.
Is there a way to do that? Or do you see any other possible solution for this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First just to clarify, when you say you tried the isBrowser check, you actually wrapped any calls to window with an `if(isBrowser) {window.example}`correct? Checking as you only mentioned placing that particular const definition in your code - it needs to be defined in each component using window and you still need to actually wrap each reference to window with an if statement checking that isBrowser constant.

That being said, if you aren't making problematic calls to window, it sounds like you may possibly be using a React dependency not written for Server-Side Rendering. One hacky solution you can try is using the library ["Loadable Components"](https://loadable-components.com/) to load the entire component during client bootstrap instead of server rendering. You can write a wrapper component that in turn calls your actual component with loadable-components:

```html
import loadable from '@loadable/component';
import React from 'react';

export default function LoadableWrapperMyComponent() {
    //Choose either Option A or B:

    //Option A: MyComponent is a JSX file representing the component you need to wrap, specify a relative path to the file
    const LoadableWrapperMyComponent = loadable(() => import('./MyComponent'), {
      fallback: <div>Loading...</div>,
    });
    
   //Option B: Same as A, but for a component from an npm package 
    const LoadableWrapperMyComponent = loadable(() => import('some-npm-package/MyNPMComponent'), {
      fallback: <div>Loading...</div>,
    });
}
```

You can then simply import and place this loadable wrapper in your JSX code where you would normally call the component.